# Compare the performance of the models and add annotations to the results

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm preparing Azure Machine Learning exam and have a question shown below:

You are working on an Azure Machine Learning Experiment.

You have the dataset configured as shown in the following table:[image: table]

You need to ensure that you can compare the performance of the models and add annotations to the results.

A. You consolidate the output of the Score Model modules by using the Add Rows module and then use the Execute R Script module.

B. You connect the Score Model modules from each trained model as inputs for the Evaluate Model module and then use the Execute R Script Module.

C. You save the output of the Score Model modules as a combined set, and then use the Project Columns modules to select the MAE.

D. You connect the Score Model modules from each trained model as inputs for the Evaluate Model module and then save the results as a dataset.

I think all of the above are correct but what confuses me is there are different answers from the internet. Some are the same with me, but others are not. I need someone to confirm my answer or explain to me the correct answer.